# String concatenation with ASP.NET MVC3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, string-concatenation

i'm trying to concatenate a string in asp.net mvc 3 razor and i'm getting a little sintax problem with my cshtml.

i what to generate an id for my checkboxes on a foreach statement, and my checkboxes should start with "chk" and what to cancatenate a fieldon the ID, something like that:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk+@obj.field" />
```

but or exampple the result for id attribute is: id="chk+8"

how can i just get a result for something like "chk8"?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just put your variable next to prefix:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk@(obj.field)" />
```

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
<input type="checkbox" id="@("chk" + obj.field)" />
```

or

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk@obj.field" />
```

Answer (score 5):

`<input type="checkbox" id="chk@(obj.field)" />` should work.

The most direct and clean way to add a prefix a suffix.

```
@("PREFIX " + obj.field + " SUFFIX")
```

Answer (score 3):

`<input type="checkbox" id="chk@(obj.field)" />` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to concate any C# variable in rozer view by using string.Format

```
id="@string.Format("{0}_Title", _Id)" // Apend after
id="@string.Format("Title_{0}", _Id)" // Apend before
id="@string.Format("Title_{0}_Title", _Id)" // Apend Middle
```